# postgres: query results into variables to be used later

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have what will end up being a complex query where certain parts will often be repeated. I would therefore like to store the results of some sub queries into variables which can then be used in the main query.

For example I would like to set the variable `'variable_id'` to be equal to a SELECT query and `variable_school_id` to be equal to another SELECT query:

```
variable_id integer := (SELECT id FROM account WHERE email = 'test@test.com');
variable_school_id integer := (SELECT school FROM account WHERE email = 'test@test.com');
```

Then I would like to make use of those variables in a query that would look like:

```
select * from doctor where account_id = variable_id AND school = variable_school_id ;
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use CTEs?

```
with params as (
      SELECT id, school
      FROM account
      WHERE email = 'test@test.com'
     )
select d.*
from params cross join
     doctor d
     on d.account_id = params.id and d.school = params.school;
```

Comment: That works for this basic example but I'm going to end up with a much more complex query with many more variables and CASE instances. So would like to do it with variables if possible?

Comment: @Charlie . . . I don't understand what you need.  You can make the `param`s CTE as complex as you like.

Comment: I didn't think that you could reference the params within a subquery.

I get the error, ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "params"
HINT:  There is an entry for table "ref_user", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: @Charlie . . . You have to include the parameters in any subquery where you reference them.